# Looking for US National Grid to Lon/Lat Converter in Python, C, or C++

Tags: raster, coordinate-system

I see here that there is Fortran source code for going from USNG to lon/lat: http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PC_PROD/USNG/

Is there some python or C/C++ code that does the same?

My understanding that this is *not* a function provided by Proj4/pyproj/GDAL, correct?

Comment: osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/MGRS-USNG-support-td2062733.html seems to suggest that you are correct that there is no proj4 support. It's from 2006 though.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Python interfaces to Fortran programs using [f2py](http://www.scipy.org/F2py). According to the web site, this facilitates:

- Calling Fortran 77/90/95, Fortran 90/95 module, and C functions from Python.
- Accessing Fortran 77 COMMON blocks and Fortran 90/95 module data (including allocatable arrays) from Python.
- Calling Python functions from Fortran or C (call-backs).
- Automatically handling the difference in the data storage order of multi-dimensional Fortran and Numerical Python (i.e. C) arrays.

The first point might serve your needs.